# Python Loop question: calling models based on variables

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

I have a basic python loop question.

Problem Statement: I have a master list of variables in list 'X', a variable 't' (which is present in master list) and another variable 'y' (which is also present in master list).

I want to run a ML model inside the loop and each time I want to remove the variable 't' and 'y' from master list 'X' and use the updated 'X' as predictor variable and rest as treatment and response variable.

Basically, I want the following algorithm -

df --> dataframe with column name as in list X

X = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

t = each element from list X with each iteration

y = ['c'] --> can be any item from list X

```
for each item in X:
    X_new = remove that item and y from X
    t_new = removed item

    df_X = df[X_new] --> dataframe df with updated list of columns in X_new
    df_t = df[t_new] --> dataframe df with just t_new column
    df_y = df[y]
    call ML model function with updated parameters df_X, df_t and df_y with each iteration
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use a list? something like... seen_numbers = set()
I know this isn't exactly what you're asking but I use lists to find duplicates or find things I want to exclude. maybe this will help...

```
this = line[92:102] + line[114:123]
if this not in seen_numbers:
    seen_numbers.add(this)
```

and you should be able to tweak this to remove what you want